# Java debugging on Eclipse: Weird Error: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse, substring

I encountered a weird occurrence while debugging in Eclipse. I am debugging the following method.

```
private String parseMessage(String msg, String uptoWord) {
    String adjusted = msg.replaceAll("(\r?\n|\r)", " ").trim();
    adjusted = adjusted.substring(0, adjusted.length() - uptoWord.length()).trim();
    return adjusted;
}
```

In the second line within the method (adjusted = msg.replaceAll("(\r?\n|\r)", " ").trim();) when I check the value of the right hand side of the assignment I get the desired value that I expect to get. However when I advance to the next line (the return statement) the value of adjusted becomes a space (" "). Thus the program returns the following exception. I cannot understand why it changes the value in the return statement. Any ideas?

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -8
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at com.emdi.sl3.server.emailConnector.EmailListenerOrderCreate.parseMessage(EmailListenerOrderCreate.java:65)
    at com.emdi.sl3.server.emailConnector.EmailListenerOrderCreate.XMLCreate(EmailListenerOrderCreate.java:57)
    at com.emdi.sl3.server.emailConnector.EmailConnectorEWS.run(EmailConnectorEWS.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Without seeing what the inputs are I don't think a meaningful answer can be given.  Most likely, you don't know how `String#substring` works.  The first index is _inclusive_, meaning you  included the first character of `adjusted`.  But the second index is _exclusive_.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I managed to solve this issue but the problem was not anything to do with the code. I did and "ant clean" and it started working as expected. Hence the issue was a class file mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Java docs for subString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) , because of bad values of beginIndex and endIndex you are getting that error.

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or
>   endIndex is larger than the length of the String object, or beginIndex
>   is larger than endIndex

.

Answer (score 0):

If `upToWord` is longer than your `adjusted` string, you're going to be `substring`ing with a negative end-bound parameter. By throwing that exception, String is telling you that you're gonna have a bad time with those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the scenario when the length of uptoWord is bigger than the length of adjusted. The negative index will cause the substring method failed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your inputs. However this problem wasn't a simple error in code. I tried a lot to solve the issue and apparently solved the issue by running an "ant clean". Thus the problem was some leftover/mismatching class files.